# Label is not showing what it has been coded to do

Tags: vb.net

```vb
totalprice = cost + cost1 + cost2 + cost3 + cost4
Form2.Label24.Text = totalprice
vat = totalprice * 0.2
Form2.Label26.Text = vat
Form2.Label27.Text = totalprice + vat
totalpricevat = totalprice + vat
Form2.Show()
finance = finance1 + totalpricevat
finance1 = totalpricevat * 0.05
finance2 = finance / 12
finance3 = totalpricevat * 0.1
finance4 = finance / 24
If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "12 Months" Then Form2.Label33.Text = finance2
If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "24 Months" Then Form2.Label33.Text = finance4
```

Above is a piece of code I made to work out finance for several chosen items.

Label33 should be showing the result of finance2 and/or finance4 depending on which item is chosen from listbox1, however it isn't working as intended, it just shows "Label33". How can I get Label33 to show the result of finance2 and/or finance4. This is very weird because last week (when I typed up this code) it was showing it fine. Today I started up the program to check if everything is working fine and this happens.

I'd appreciate any help and please do explain every part of your answer as I'm fairly new to Visual Basic

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting the breakpoint and debug. I think it's quite easy to find the problem, my friend.

Comment: You should give meaningful names to your controls. Label33 etc, are not meaningful names.

Comment: Please, and can not stress this enough.  As Mary says decent meaningful names for controls and variables.  It's not for our benefit, it's for your own.  That aside, the problem will likely be ListBox1.SelectedItem doesn't equal either "12 Months" or "24 Months".  I would be surprised if it ever would as SelectedItem returns an Object that you're comparing to a string.  Perhaps listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() is the fix?

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 0):

You never use finance3 in your code. You are charging exactly the same finance charge for 1 year as you have for 2 years. That is a deal I would like. I know this excercise is asking you to be both an accountant and a programmer. You have the value of finance1 calculated after you use it to calculate finance1.

I added values for the cost variables so I could test.

I did the calculations for finance in the If statement so you only calculated one option.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim cost = 10D, cost1 = 20D, cost2 = 30D, cost3 = 40D, cost4 = 50D
    Dim totalprice = cost + cost1 + cost2 + cost3 + cost4
    Form2.Label24.Text = totalprice.ToString("N2")
    Dim vat = totalprice * 0.2
    Form2.Label26.Text = vat.ToString("N2")
    Form2.Label27.Text = (totalprice + vat).ToString("N2")
    Dim totalpricevat = totalprice + vat
    'Dim finance3 = totalpricevat * 0.1   You never use this in your code.
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "12 Months" Then
        Dim finance = totalpricevat * 1.05 / 12
        Form2.Label33.Text = finance.ToString("N2")
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "24 Months" Then
        Dim finance = totalpricevat * 1.1 / 24 ' .1 is .05 x 2, interest for 2 years
        Form2.Label33.Text = finance.ToString("N2")
    End If
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```